# Как визуализировать игру "Сапёр"?

Tags: php

Написал игру консольную на php, есть два вопроса:

1. Как сделать, чтобы в консоли поле было статичным, а не отрисовывалось полностью при каждом ходе? Сюда же вопрос о таймере: как его сделать?
2. Куда посмотреть и что используют чтобы сделать графическую составляющую игры?

Comment: почему все думают что визуализация и php - это рядом стоящие вещи?

Что сайты - это php? что за созданием сайта стоит только программист, и нет в природе никаких дизайнеров и верстальщиков - это мифы, придуманные злостными программистами. НЕ существует никаких JS скриптов, верстки и каскадных таблиц. Все исключительно делается на php.

ps вопрос про консоль, да никак ты в ней не сделаешь AJAX!

Comment: [Свежее с хабра](http://habrahabr.ru/post/168435/)

Answer (score 2):

php не может выводить символы в определенные позиции в консоли, для него есть только поток вывода, это вам не системный язык программирования.

Comment: Ну, вывернуться-то всегда можно. 

Например, можно написать программу на Си, которая получает через параметры символ и позицию на экране и осуществлять вывод вызывая ее.

Comment: можно хоть на ассемблере, но это уже не будет программа на PHP :)

Comment: А как же PHP-GTK, думается мне, этот костыль можно приспособить)

Comment: @Shock, это будет уже не консольная, а оконная программа.

Вообще, не знаю, но может в ПХП есть какой-нибудь curses модуль?